# Request scoped bean inside a Singleton bean

Tags: spring, scope, request, javabeans

I have  a web app where i define 2 bean
1 with a singleton scope and one with a request scope.
I need the request scoped bean inside the singleton bean.

So i ended up with this

```
<bean id="routingDataSource" class="org.ai2l.ifsr.service.multiTenants.RoutingDataSource" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <property name="targetDataSources" value="#{tenantSpecificDependencyFactory.tenantIdToDataSource}"/>
    <!-- <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="parentDataSource"/>         -->
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ifsrPU"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="routingDataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">
              org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```

As you will notice i've use the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>`but it isn't working.
I've also tryed the

```
  <listener>
<listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
```

inside my web.xml. But none of this is working.

I still get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Does any one know why this happens??

Comment: Hibernate does some database checking at startup (database version, type etc) for this it needs a connection, which it is going to retrieve from the datasource. As that is a request scoped bean and there is no active request at startup of your application, that will fail.

Comment: So i assume that, if i do make "load-on-startup" lower than 1 then the application will be fine.
Is that correct?

Comment: It depends. If this is the configuration that is loaded with the `ContextLoaderListener`, as it should be, the `load-on-startup` of the `DispatcherServlet` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In my case it's the dispacherSerlvet thaht handle the context's loading.
So the context was reloaded on each request.

Comment: What i ended up doing was to make my routingDataBase singleton. And eventually grab the request if possible using the `RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.request`.
Because my issue was caused by the fact that the request scope was not available at the time of using it (for hibernate validation)